# How does the hashing trick work in NLP

Tags: nlp, dimensionality-reduction

If I have 1000 words and want to reduce the dimension to 500, does that mean per hash there will be two words on average?
In the course NLP specialization on courser, 40 million unique word matrix was reduced to 4 million word matrix.I can only imagine how many collisions will be there, but it turns out that there would not be may collisions.
Can anyone please throw some light on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please include the link to the course in your answer?